# Conditional Expectation: LOTE or Simple Reasoning?

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, self-learning

> A group of 42 ladybugs and 28 are caught with probability p, independently. After an extremely reliable bug catcher goes out, he comes back with 10 bugs. Given this information, what is the expected number of ladybugs caught?

So, first and foremost, it is important to note that each bug is caught with probability $\frac{1}{7}$. From there, we can realize that the proportion of bugs is 3:2,  and thus, of the 10 bugs caught, the expected number of ladybugs caught is $\frac{3}{5}$ * 10 = 6. Is this type of logic correct? Can I utilize this via linearity and expectation?

Comment: Not necessarily, @PaulSinclair. We know 10 bugs were caught, NOT ladybugs. How many are likely to be lady bugs, is essentially what it is saying.

Comment: My apologies. I failed to notice the distinction in bug types.

Comment: But this leaves the problem under-specified. The only information given is in group of ladybugs, how many are likely to be caught. There is no information on how this compares to other bugs. Indeed no information about other bugs at all. Without that, you cannot answer the question. Or is that rather ungrammatical first sentence mistated?